# Sticky menu width 100% but not filling screen

Tags: html, css, hubspot

We have a sticky menu on our site (http://462184.hs-sites.com/) with the width set to 100%. However as you can see the menu is still falling short on the left by a few pixels.

I can't work out what it is conflicting with. Your help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you just missing to give `left:positionvalue` in css. please use `.custom_menu-container.nav-sticky{left:0;}`... Done.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it for you, just copy and paste the whole thing
Find:
.custom_menu-container.nav-sticky{background:#29a2f3;position:fixed!important;top:0;transition:all .5s ease 0s;width:100%;z-index:10}

in http://cdn2.hubspot.net/hub/462184/hub_generated/style_manager/1427950593779/custom/page/PocketBookkeeping_Feb2015-theme/PocketBookkeeping_Feb2015-style.min.css

Replace it with:

```
.custom_menu-container.nav-sticky{background:#29a2f3;position:fixed!important;top:0;transition:all .5s ease 0s;width:100%;z-index:10;left:0;}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make these changes:

```
.custom_menu-container.nav-sticky{
    left: 0; /* add */
    postition: fixed; /* remove !important */
}
```